# Validating 2 models with ModelState.IsValid and FluentValidation validator in .NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, modelstate

In my API project I have multiple endpoints for simple CRUD operations. The endpoints use FluentValidation to validate the supplied models by adding the Validators to the DI and using `ModelState.IsValid`.

The ModelState.IsValid works fine when there is just one model as parameter, but as soon I have multiple models then only the first get's validated, the following example makes this issue a bit claerer:

My `UPDATE` endpoint operation takes 2 parameters (Id and model):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateMedium([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = ValidationClass.UPDATE)] [FromRoute] long id, [FromBody] Medium model)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }

        if (id != model.MediumID)
        {
            return this.BadRequest();
        }

        // Etc....

    }
```

The `this.ModelState.IsValid` now only validates the first model (Id) and the second model get's ignored. 
What would be the best approach of validating both models?

The Id parameter is obviously quite simple but I made a FluentValidation validator for it anyway (in case we want to add more validating logic to it in the future):

```
public class IdValidator : AbstractValidator<long>
{
    public IdValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r => r).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Id is empty.");
    }
}
```

Additionally, the Medium model validator looks as follow:

```
    public class MediumValidator : AbstractValidator<Medium>
    {

        public MediumValidator()
        {
            RuleSet(ValidationClass.CREATE, Create);
            RuleSet(ValidationClass.UPDATE, Update);
        }

        private void Create()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.InsertDateTime).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.InsertUserID).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.SolutionID).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not filled in.");
            RuleFor(r => r.Name).MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("The length of {PropertyName} must be {MaxLength} characters or fewer. You entered {TotalLength} characters.");
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            RuleFor(r => r.UpdateDateTime).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.UpdateUserID).Empty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.MediumID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is empty.");
            RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is not filled in.");
            RuleFor(r => r.Name).MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("The length of {PropertyName} must be {MaxLength} characters or fewer. You entered {TotalLength} characters.");
        }

    }
```

Perhaps I should only use the model as parameter and then just make the ID field required?

**UPDATE**

The setup of the FluentValidation in the startup:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
            {
                fv.RunDefaultMvcValidationAfterFluentValidationExecutes = false;
            });

            // Add fluent validators
            services.AddTransient<IValidator<long>, IdValidator>();
            services.AddTransient<IValidator<Medium>, MediumValidator>();
```

**UPDATE2:**

I am using swagger to test the endpoint (JSON input).

Comment: _multiple models_?  You can't have multiple models in an action, since only one model can be deserialized due to the nature of TCP/IP connections (once it's read, you can't rewind it anymore). The model should work. What is `CustomizeValidatorAttribute`? a `[FromRoute]` and another `[FromBody]` should not conflict by itself. Must be something on your setup or with fluent validation

Comment: Strange then, I added the setup of my FluentValidation in the main post.

Answer (score 1):

For now I have implemented a different approach. For the UPDATE operation I now manually add the Medium model errors to the `ModelState`:

```
var validator = new MediumValidator();
var result = validator.Validate(model, ruleSet: ValidationClass.UPDATE);
result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState, null);

if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
}
```

Better solutions are always welcome!